# wmserver suddently power off during no working time

Tags: esxi

We have two esx server and two cluster .One cluser is vmserver and another is vmclient.In vmclient have 100 virtual machine (window 7) .This is use thin cline.Soon among its one virtual machine is suddenly power off.No break down electricity .Thank ..